# i would like to use jquery to add value and name to a select option such that it displays the current valye assigned by the jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-4

the anchor tag to display the modal

```
<?php
echo "<a href='#edit_task'  data-toggle='modal' data-id='$info_id' data-startd='$startdate' data-endd='$finishdate' data-pro='$progress' data-started='$status_id'><i class='fas fa-edit fa-lg fa-fw'></i></a>";
?>
```

the modal data

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_task">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">add new user</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">        

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label for="progress">progress</label>
```

here is where the problem lies it does not display the current value in the option as declared in the jQuery

```
                <select id="progress" class="form-control" name="prog">
                    <option value ="1">0%</option>
                    <option value="2">25%</option>
                    <option value="3">50%</option>
                    <option value="4">100%</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the modal footer

```
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <?php
            echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='edit' onclick='return mess()'; >";
            echo "save";
            echo "</button>";
            ?>
        </div>
```

alert box for saving data

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function mess(){
                        alert ("the new user is successfully saved");
                        return true;
                    }
                </script>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the jquery code if possible a code to add value in the `<select>` so that it detects both name and value

```
<script>
    $('#edit_task').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var progg= $(e.relatedTarget).data('pro');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('select[name="prog"]').val(progg);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What does `$progress` has in it ?

Comment: eg 0%,50%,75% am reading that data fro the databse

Answer (score 0):

You have use `.val(progg)` in your jquery code  it will search for option where `value="proggvalue"` but here your `option value` are `1,2..` so its not able to find which one to set selected.Instead , use `$(e.currentTarget).find("#progress option:contains("+progg+")").attr("selected",true);` this will find option *text* which has value `progg`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#edit_task').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var progg = $(e.relatedTarget).data('pro');
  console.log(progg)
  //remove attr selected
  $('#progress option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
  //find option where .text progg
  $(e.currentTarget).find("#progress option:contains(" + progg + ")").attr("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href='#edit_task' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$info_id' data-startd='$startdate' data-endd='$finishdate' data-pro='25%' data-started='$status_id'><i class='fas fa-edit fa-lg fa-fw'>Click</i></a>
<a href='#edit_task' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$info_id' data-startd='$startdate' data-endd='$finishdate' data-pro='100%' data-started='$status_id'><i class='fas fa-edit fa-lg fa-fw'>Click</i></a>
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_task">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">add new user</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="progress">progress</label>

            <select id="progress" class="form-control" name="prog">
              <option value="1">0%</option>
              <option value="2">25%</option>
              <option value="3">50%</option>
              <option value="4">100%</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='edit' onclick='return mess()' ;></button>
        </div>
```